# Error String types not allowed

Tags: string, textcolor

sorry  I'm beginner  when i build the app it show me that  error

String types not allowed (at 'android:text Color Primary' with value 'TITLE_COLOR_GOES_HERE').

Comment: I explained how you can get rid of this problem and use Colors in your textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use some color there are two ways :

Either you can directly use colorcode

`yourTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);`

Or you can define some color in your colors.xml file in resource and use it 
`yourTextView.setTextColor(colors.red);`

While setting color , you need to either define that color name as string in your colors.xml file in your resources folder (res) or use like Color.RED or your preferable color